# ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ora-12560

we have a dot net application and it connecting to Oracle and fetching data and moving to SQL server. it was working very fine. just started giving error **ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error** . Tnsping also giving this error. but if i stop this application and tnsping then its success. again starting the application on the first 10 minutes its working perfectly and gain giving same error. every 5 seconds this application connecting to Oracle databse.

any idea what is this error; and how to resolve. there is lots of questions over here,but didnt find a soulution .

highly appreciate your comments against this query

Comment: If your application is connecting every 5 secs, then you should consider just keeping the connection open instead.

Comment: Thanks AR, ill look into your suggetion

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have some sort of resource leak. Do you close connections properly ?

Also, as [ar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276138/ar) said in comment, why don't you just keep this connection open ? IIRC Establishing conn is costly operation in any DBMS.

Also, from documentation:

---

ORA-12560 -- TNS:protocol adapter error
**Cause**: A generic protocol adapter error occurred.
**Action**: Check addresses used for proper protocol specification. Before reporting this error, look at the error stack and check for lower level transport errors. For further details, turn on tracing and reexecute the operation. Turn off tracing when the operation is complete.

---

**UPDATE**:
Problem could be caused by overflow of Windows event journal. Check Oracle's events here:
*Start menu => Control Panel => Administrative Tools => Event Viewer*
You should either clear journal manually or increase its' size

Comment: Thanks Alexander,ill go through this update . thank you for the suggetions.